# Rail3 button_to remote custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make button with custom remote action
when i try

```
<%= button_to "something", {:controller => :updates, :action => :new}, {:remote => true} %>
```

it works fine but if I change :action to my own defined action in controller

```
<%= button_to "something", {:controller => :updates, :action => :destroy_all, :method => :delete}, {:remote => true} %>
```

the generated path in form is wrong

```
<form action="/assets?action=destroy_all&controller=updates&method=delete" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

In updates_controller I have defined :destroy_all

```
def destroy_all
    #some spaghetti code
end
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to). The `:method` belongs in the `html_options`, not in the `options`:

```
<%= button_to "something", {:controller => :updates, :action => :destroy_all}, {:remote => true, :method => :delete} %>
```

You also need to add a route in your routes file that points to `"updates#destroy_all"`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem isn't in change method name. You not correctly pass options. See

```
action="/assets?action=destroy_all&controller=updates&method=delete"
```

I thinl it's not what you want. Try

```
<%= button_to "smth", {:controller => :updates, :method => :destroy_all}, {:remote => true, :method => :delete} %>
```

or

```
<%= button_to "smth", '/updates/destroy_all', {:remote => true, :method => :delete} %>
```

Be careful to use method delete =)

Comment: `:method => :destroy_all` is wrong. Other than that your answer is the same as mine.

Comment: sorry. :method => :delete_all change to :action => :delete_all